# Mac sound output doesnt switch to laptop speakers after removing headphones

Tags: macos, mac, audio, speakers

The system config shows which speaker should be on.
But the sound only comes from headphones when I attach them.
To use the normal speakers, I have to restart OSX (10.6.8).

If I plugin headphones in any session, then I can only used headphones, until I restart.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with OSX for a long time. Maybe this will help: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3883839